# Update Manager stop working

Tags: package-management, ppa, skype

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 i386. After trying to install Skype, the update manager crashes. I tried to use the console using the commands `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get update -f` and always the same. Error 404 with this message

```
"W: Falhou obter http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]".
```

Already tried some of your solutions and already verified PPA. Can't find the problem. Update manager still doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

Answer (score 3):

Had this same problem happen to me.  The Software Center created the following file which needs to be removed.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive.canonical.com_commercial-ppa-uploaders_skype_ubuntu.list
```

Then, follow the instructions [here](http://www.multimediaboom.com/how-to-install-skype-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal/) for configuring the Software Center.  Not sure why it gives you the option to install skype before you do that.  Kind of a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'll tell you what I know about fixing this problem. The simple fact is I'm not a programmer so any help I can provide will be basic but I'll do my best.

The following I must warn you aside from the first set of commands is unlikely to work without removing Skype.

Have you tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo --configure -a
```

If that doesn't work you could always remove the ppa manually using the commands I'll give momentarily.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And verify using your password.
Go down to where you see the ppa in question plus one with, 'src' in the ppa name.

Comment: Tanks! still dont work, but I think that some PPA line that some how, it was modified!